# One to one aiming in 2D platformer

Tags: 2d, unity, platformer, joystick, aiming

Hello all I have been having an issue with a 2D platformer I'm working on in Unity. It has an aiming style similar to Shadow Complex where the aiming will rotate around the character in direction to wherever the right joystick (360 controller) will be facing. Here's some expert drawings to visualize the issue.

[image]
[image]

What I have currently working involves raycasts and getting it to rotate which works and is fun but I would really prefer to have the cursor "snap" to the correct position. I'm not sure if I'm on to the correct way to do this or if my "snapping" method is the best possible way to do this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to our site. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome (long time lurker) what I'm currently doing is creating a plane and firing a ray in the position of the joystick. The using viewportPointToRay to return the position to the aiming script which then rotates the cursor at the correct angle using a quaternion rotation. This creates the rotating effect. I've updated the original post with the code I'm using.

Comment: Haha, "expert drawings" :D

Comment: Are you just trying to get the aiming crosshair to snap to a location around the character?

Comment: Yes. In relation to where the right joystick is pointing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating this quite a bit. If I understood you right, you want to allow the player to aim to any degree, but this will snap to specific presets (like 8 directions).

To "snap" a value to one of `number_of_steps` equidistant values between a `minimum` and `maximum` value (talking about angles most likely `0` and `360`, or `0` and `2 * Math.PI` or whatever) you can use a rather easy expression:

```
snapped = (Math.Round(((value - minimum) / (maximum - minimum)) * number_of_steps, 0) / number_of_steps) * (maximum - minimum) + minimum;
```

This is a bit complicated, so here's the simplified variation assuming your value's range is always from 0 to 1:

```
snapped = Math.Round(value * number_of_steps, 0) / number_of_steps;
```

It's rather easy to understand once you know the general idea: By multiplicating a value between 0 and 1 with ne number of steps and then rounding the result you essentially force the result to be a multiple of `1 / number_of_steps`. With the final division you're scaling the value back to the range between 0 and 1.

---

Here's an example:

- You've got the value 0.67 and you'd like to snap it to one of 4 possible positions (i.e. 0, 0.25, 0.5, or 0.75; 1 would be the same as 0).
- Multiplying your value by 4 you'll end up with 2.68.
- Rounded this will be 3.
- After dividing it by 4, you'll get 0.75, which is indeed the closest point.

---

Now, to apply this to your problem, all you have to do is determine the angle the player is aiming to (hint: `Math.Atan2()`). Scale this to the range between 0 and 1, apply the formula above, scale it back and use it to rotate your turret, bullet, whatever.

Comment: This is exactly the conceptual unwiring I needed. Thank you for helping me get there.